# Spyder Debug - How to fix code and Continue stepping

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I am using Spyder (3.2.6) on a Mac, running python code that starts by loading/processing some large data files.

When stepping through my code if I encounter an error, is it possible to fix the error and continue stepping - rather than run everything from the beginning again (and wait for all the data to load/process)?

Encountering an error seems to 'end' the run/debug mode at the point of the error, and I can't seem to find a way to continue.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think it's not possible to do what you want because your code needs to be loaded in memory to be able to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for responding.